# Pass an integer array from JSP to JS

Tags: javascript, jsp, data-conversion

In my JSP I have an integer array where each integer has 19 digits. I am passing this array to a javascript function. Since javascript supports numbers in the range +/- 9007199254740992, the last three digits of all the integers in integer array is converted to zeroes.

For example in JSP - the integer array is [6918384653328004118 , 9016587993063058147]
In javascript function, I receive this integer array as [6918384653328004000 , 9016587993063058000]

Please let me know how I can pass the complete 19 digit integer array to javascript function.

Thanks,
Surabhi

Comment: Javascript numbers are actually IEEE-754 doubles. There is no other number type in Javascript. Thus, since a double has approx. 16 decimal digits accuracy, this might be a non-trivial task. One might need to develop a custom number representation to keep the 19 digit long ints. Some 3rd party libraries might however already exist.

Comment: What will you be using the numbers for? I take it simply representing them as strings isn't good enough because you want to do mathematical operations on them? There are some BigInteger type libraries for JavaScript that let you do that.

Comment: I will not use these numbers for calculations, it will be used for building another URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not intend to use these integers for calculation, can you just pass to your Javascript as Strings and treat them as Strings in your JS code?

Instead of generating an array of numbers (`[6918384653328004118 , 9016587993063058147]`), change your JSP so it wraps your numbers in quotes (`["6918384653328004118" , "9016587993063058147"]`). Javascript interprets that as an array of Strings.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, After changing the number to string by adding quotes, JS receives all 19 digits.